# Android - Google Fit API, validate if account is setup properly

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm successful in asking for required permissions and actually getting the data from Google Fit API.
What I want to validate before I access API data is - if the user/account is set up properly (not permissions, but actually authorized and everything is ready to read data correctly).

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started#try_the_rest_api_in_the_oauth_playground) REST API. This is the easy way to test your setup with the Fitness by submitting HTTP requests and observing the responses and protocol and APIs.